# Returning a Formatted NSString From NSNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created a database that contains a number of values against other data.

Typically the Number will be in the form of: 40000 or similar.
I would like to display this in a form as a NSString like '40,000'.

How would this be best achieved ?

Fritzables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set format like this

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"##,##,###"];      
NSString *formattedNumberString = [numberFormatter 
  stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1234567]];
NSLog(@"formattedNumberString: %@", formattedNumberString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a category for NSNumber. Or get a C manual and check at all the ways to format a number in C, which all applies to +NSString stringWithFormat as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    NSString *formatedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourValueFromDatabase];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do as follows:

```
   NSNumber *YourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123456789];
   NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
   NSString *FormattedNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue:YourNumber];
   NSLog(@"value : %@", FormattedNumber);
```

or

```
NSString * formatedString = [NSNumber stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",yourNumber];
```

If you want for thousand of records you can use for loop.

Hope this will help :)